# libgit2 and Qt error

Tags: c++, qt, libgit2

I want to use git from an Qt application. So far, I use QProcess, but I do not want to use that. So I found libgit2.

This works as expected:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "git2.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    git_repository* repo = 0;
    git_clone(&repo, "/path_to/barerep", "/path_to/test_clone", NULL);
    git_repository_free(repo);
    repo = 0;
}
```

But here, git_clone crashes.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    git_repository* repo = 0;
    git_clone(&repo, "/path_to/barerep", "/path_to/test_clone", NULL);
    git_repository_free(repo);
    repo = 0;

    return a.exec();
}
```

The error is:
    *** Error in `/path_to/gittest': free(): invalid pointer: 0x09d53a88 ***

Any suggestions? Of course, omitting QApplication is not an alternative. The same error occurs without `return a.exec()`.

Note: Actually, there is a class GitRepository with a method `clone(const QString & url)` (the path is stored somewhere in the class).

Again, this works

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    GitRepository g;
    g.clone("path_to/barerep");
}
```

But this does not. (QObject!)

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QObject();  // <--
    GitRepository g;
    g.clone("path_to/barerep");
}
```

does not.

```
bool GitRepository::clone(const QString & url)
{
    git_repository* repo = 0;
    git_clone(&repo, CSTR(url), CSTR(path()), NULL);
    git_repository_free(repo);
    repo = 0;

    //loadFromTempDir();

    return true;
}
```

Replacing QApplication by QObject in the first example suppresses the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call [git_libgit2_init()](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/libgit2/git_libgit2_init) before calling any other libgit2 functions. As the documentation says:

> This function must the called before any other libgit2 function in order to set up global state and threading.

Comment: `error: 'git_libgit2_init' was not declared in this scope`. I use the libgit2 version 0.19.0-2 (from Ubuntu 14.04 repository). All the examples I read so far did not mention `git_libgit2_init()`.

Comment: It seems to work with libgit2 version in Ubunutu repository too. Replace `git_libgit2_init()` with `git_threads_init()`

Answer (score 0):

These kind of errors are really hard to find. I also had problems mixing Qt libraries with other libraries. The trick is to organize your code in a way that there is only one library included in one compilation unit.

Create a class, which wraps around libgit2, and only include the libgit2 headers in the cpp file of this class. Do not include any qt headers in the same file.

Only refer to libgit throw your wrapper. Sure it seems like a lot of work, but as a result your code will be cleaner, and these misterious errors will be gone.

Comment: Yeah, I know this trick from developing with CUDA or OpenGL. Unfortunately, it does not work. See [code](http://pastebin.com/3pnT7QDQ). But the error is different: Segfault at line `return a.exec()`. Btw, the clone seems to succeed.

Comment: Strange. It looks fine to me. Could you also post your project file? Maybe there is a trace ...

Comment: The [.pro File](http://pastebin.com/kDJbru5L). It is freshly generated but the `LIBS += -lgit2` is added.

Comment: I see the problem. You will either need to add GUI to your configuration or use QCoreApplication instead of QApplication.

Comment: Well, I did use QCoreApplication. Sorry for confusion, I exchanged QApplication by QCoreApplication in the last example. It actually does not affect the issue.

Comment: Well, then run qmake + clean/rebuild and hope for the best :D I am out of ideas, sorry ...

Comment: I just changed back to QApplication, and the error is the same as before: \*** Error in \`/path_to/gittest': free(): invalid pointer: 0x09bb0a88 \***, in `git_clone()`.